# RadioButtonList DataBinding When Previously Checked

Tags: c#, asp.net

Don't know why this is so difficult, but I have Yes No radio buttons linked to a field. When the record is called I would like the record's answer (Yes or No) selected in the radio button. My code is not recognizing the id of the radio button. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" %>

<script runat="server">

protected void frmProfiles_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{
RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
}

protected void onYesNochanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (rblYesNo.SelectedItem.Text == "yes")
;
else
;
}
</script>



<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">


<asp:FormView
id="frmProfiles"
DataSourceID="srcProfiles"
DataKeyNames="State"
Runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<h1>State: <%# Eval("State") %></h1>
<b>1. Is the SMHA Director/Commissioner a member of the Governor's Cabinet?</b>
<%#Eval("O_1") %>
<br />
<br />

<br />
<br />
<asp:LinkButton
id="lnkEdit"
Text="Edit State Information"
CommandName="Edit"
Runat="server" />

</ItemTemplate>

<EditItemTemplate>

<b>1. Is the SMHA Director/Commissioner a member of the Governor's Cabinet?</b>
<br />

<br />


<asp:Label
id="lblYesNo"
DataSourceID="srcProfiles"
DataKeyNames="State"
AssociatedControlID="rblYesNo"
Runat="server" >
<asp:RadioButtonList id="rblYesNo" 
Runat="server" 
enabled="true" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="onYesNochanged" >
<asp:ListItem  Text="Yes"    Value="Yes" />
<asp:ListItem  Text="No"    Value="No" />   
</asp:RadioButtonList > 
</asp:Label>     
<br /><br />

|

<asp:LinkButton
id="lnkUpdate"
Text="Update State Information"
CommandName="Update"
Runat="server" />
    |
<asp:LinkButton
id="lnkCancel"
Text="Cancel Update"
CommandName="Cancel"
Runat="server" />
</EditItemTemplate>

</asp:FormView>
<br />
Click on State Initials to go to next page.<br />
<asp:GridView
id="grdState"
DataSourceID="srcNext"
ShowHeader="false"
Runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:HyperLinkField
DataTextField="State"
DataNavigateUrlFields="State"
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Org2.aspx?State={0}" />
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>



<asp:AccessDataSource ID="srcProfiles" 
SelectCommand="SELECT State, O_1 FROM [P13Organization]
WHERE State=AG"
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [P13Organization] SET State=@State, O_1=@O_1
WHERE State=@State"
DataFile="K:\3NRI\Profiles\Profiles.mdb"
runat="server">

<SelectParameters>
<asp:QueryStringParameter
Name="State"
QueryStringField="State" />
</SelectParameters>   
</asp:AccessDataSource> 

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="srcNext" 
SelectCommand="SELECT State FROM [P13Organization]
WHERE State=@State"
DataFile="K:\3NRI\Profiles\Profiles.mdb"
runat="server">

<SelectParameters>
<asp:QueryStringParameter
Name="State"
QueryStringField="State" />
</SelectParameters>    
</asp:AccessDataSource> 

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

rblYesNo is inside a FormView, so you have to do something like this (not tested):

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)frmProfiles.Items.FindControl("rblYesNo");
if (rb.SelectedItem.Text == "Yes") etc
```

Comment: Better yet, use `frmProfiles.Items.FindControl("rblYesNo") as RadioButton` and then perform a null check, so you can properly handle the situation where this fails, rather than simply throwing a NRE.

Comment: Ant P is right - I do usually do a check for rb == null before the if statement